# ContentPresenter not displaying Custom Control in Style

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, contentpresenter

I have a Custom Control, NumericUpDown. I created a named style in which I want to extend the control, in this case by wrapping it in a Grid and adding a Label.

When I use the button as a basic example, I can extend upon the ControlTemplate just fine. The original Button is shown in the location of the ContentPresenter, and I can add other controls around it for layout and whatever.

```
ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However when using my Custom Control, the ContentPresenter doesn't show the NumericUpDown control, it shows absolutely nothing. Even in its most basic form I can't get the ContentPresenter to show the Custom Control.

```
<Style x:Key="LabeledNumericUpDown2"  TargetType="{x:Type controls:NumericUpDown}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:NumericUpDown}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Blabla"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <!--<controls:NumericUpDown Grid.Column="1"/>-->
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what I am missing.

Thanks for your help, it is much appreciated!

**Edit**

The NumericUpDown Custom Control also has a default style that defines the NumericUpDown control. I wish to extend upon this with the named style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:NumericUpDown}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:NumericUpDown}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" Margin="0" 
                        Text="{Binding DisplayValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0 1 1 1" BorderBrush="#FFABADB3">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="8" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="8" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Button x:Name="PART_ButtonUp" Grid.Row="0" Content="▲" FontSize="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Padding="6 1 0 0" />
                            <Button x:Name="PART_ButtonDown" Grid.Row="1" Content="▼" FontSize="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Padding="6 1 0 0" />

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some `Controls` define and expect specific named elements to function correctly otherwise known as Parts.

Make sure that your `ControlTemplate` has provided the required parts for the `Control` in order for it to render correctly.

**Edit:**

Try this `ControlTemplate` to get you started.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:NumericUpDown}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Blabla"/>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" Margin="0" 
                Text="{Binding DisplayValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0 1 1 1" BorderBrush="#FFABADB3">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="8" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="8" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Button x:Name="PART_ButtonUp" Grid.Row="0" Content="▲" FontSize="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Padding="6 1 0 0" />
                    <Button x:Name="PART_ButtonDown" Grid.Row="1" Content="▼" FontSize="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Padding="6 1 0 0" />

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Sorry the question isn't clear. The custom control also has a default style. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Cheers for the quick answer. I tried what you mentioned but even with the most basic test and a default style without Parts, the ContentPresenter doesn't display anything at all.

Comment: I've edited with an example ControlTemplate to play with.

Comment: Yes that is a solution, but I am trying to avoid too much duplicate XAML for maintainability. So I hoped to reuse the ControlTemplate from the default style without copy-paste inside the named-style ControlTemplate. But I think I realized the problem, the ContentPresenter doesn't display the entire control if I understand correctly?

Comment: As you are overriding the ControlTemplate for a specific type of control, you won't be able to use an instance of the control within it's own template.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I got a new question now :) but as far as this one goes, you helped me a ton!